# Loading an image from Google Cloud Bucket with PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to get an image from google cloud bucket in a similar fashion to file_get_contents? I need the image for mess around with without needing to have it on my local machine/server

i have tried using the google cloud storage library for php (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-storage) but it keeps giving me "failed to open stream" error, which leads me to believe that I may provided the wrong url to the file_get_content function.

I should mention that all the files are set to public, with public storage.cloud.google.com links available

My current code is similar to this:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient();
$storage->registerStreamWrapper();

$contents = file_get_contents('gs://{BUCKET}/{IMAGE NAME}.jpg');
```

While my current bucket structure is more like this

BUCKET - FOLDER - IMAGE

I have tried adding the folder in the URL and it still gave me the same "failed to open stream" error. Could anyone point me at what am i doing wrong? Do I need to authenticate? Do I even need the library for this? I tried using file_get_content($public_url) but since storage.cloud.google.com links redirect you that obviously didn't work hahaha

Any help would be appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed the Cloud SDK, and used the default service account credentials to connect to Google Cloud services [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/master/AUTHENTICATION.md).

> In general, the Google Cloud PHP library uses Service Account
>   credentials to connect to Google Cloud services. When running on
>   Compute Engine the credentials will be discovered automatically. When
>   running on other environments, the Service Account credentials can be
>   specified by providing the path to the JSON keyfile for the account
>   (or the JSON itself) in environment variables.

1. Run `composer require google/cloud`
2. Create a test.php file:

   ```
   <?php
   # Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
   require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

   # Imports the Google Cloud client library
   use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

   # Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
   $projectId = 'my_project';

   # Instantiates a client
   $storage = new StorageClient([
   'projectId' => $projectId
   ]);

   # The name for the new bucket
   $storage->registerStreamWrapper();

   $contents = file_get_contents('gs://my-buck-sample/image.JPG');

   echo 'content' . $contents . ' created.';
   ?>
   ```

3.Run `php test.php`

Comment: Thanks! The issue was that I didn't add a service key yet